# error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`. warn Please

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, sdk

I can't launch my Android simulator. I have Android Studio installed as well as a couple of simulators. Any help appreciated!

```
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.


error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the environment variable in your mac system.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
copy those texts
type nano ~/.zshrc in mac terminal
source ~/.zshrc
paste copied texts
To save it, hit Ctrl + X, type Y to save, and then enter to keep the file name as it is.
```

Comment: When I do yarn android the simulator starts but console logs same errors and app does not show. I edited the nano file.

Comment: @kore24 did you install JDK? if not then please install JDK 15
you can check open terminal and write javac if it is run then no need to install JDK or no need to set JAVA_HOME