# Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot

Tags: react-native

I am installing React Native according to this website
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
it's very useful until I run the command react-native run-android, this is the error I receive:
Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
after i launch an emulator manually project build successfully but application is installed but not open?

- create new emulator
- increase space of emulator
- wipe data of emulator
- cold boot emulator
- uninstall application
- clean gradle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of \`emulator -list-avds\`. warn Please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235069/error-failed-to-launch-emulator-reason-no-emulators-found-as-an-output-of-emu)